# Receive Cognito Form results as Plain Text email

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to receive the email notification with entry details from a submitted Cognito Form in plain text?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to include entry details in the body portion of the message by picking fields to include in the message body.  This is an alternative to selecting to include all entry details, which uses a table to show each field and value.

However, even if only the message body is included, the email is still sent as an HTML email message, with limited formatting.  Is this your question, to send just as a true plain text email with absolutely no formatting.  If so, would you describe the scenario where this is helpful?

We worked hard to ensure that the email notifications would look good (or at least be readable) on mobile devices.  However, email is a tricky thing, so any insight into your specific needs will be helpful.